# configurable products don't show up shipment method in checkout

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I am trying to make a configurable product (clothes with size and color) shipped. When I create a simple product I see shipment method : 
[image]

But when I select a configurable product (choose the size and the color), I don't see the shipment method and I'm forwarded directly to the payment page. And I must say these products have weight.

[image]

When I see to the DB (table catalog_product_entity), I see the main product is Configurable while the others (combination size-color) are virtual. I hanged the "virtual" attribute to "simple" , still didn't work

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested a configurable product with Magento 2.2.2 version. When creating a configurable product with child products which are 'automatically' generated. These child items will have no weight. As a result, they are virtual products. It's a default Magento (in my case, Magento 2.2.2).

We can change the `type_id` in `catalog_product_entity` table (As you said, you did it, but no success). I think the reason for that you enabled Flat table: **Catalog > Store Front > Use Flat Catalog Product**. In this case, we need to **reindex** our database.

Comment: Sorry couldn't upvote your answer because I have less than 15 reputations

Comment: @IsmailBerlin no worries. Just want to check my knowledge also.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i have same issue facing but my client is not adding weight in all products so my all product is simple products and no weight available also when i run reindex command then 2-3 day working fine after some time then this issue coming again

Answer (score 3):

You can convert all virtual products to the simple product by just one query.

```
update catalog_product_entity set type_id = 'simple' where type_id = 'virtual';
```

**But beware, this query converts all virtual products to simple. (better to create DB backup before the start)**

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by manually adding `weights` to individual products if the product list is not bigger. I had similar issue and I solved it by adding `weights` to the products. This approach has two benefit. The variations of products will not list on the cart & shipping option missing `error` is also managed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding weights to the products. Thanks.
Magento 2.3.5

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

this is a quick fix
you need to edit this file vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php

public function isVirtual()

and make it return false